# Which HTTP status code to say username or password were incorrect?

Tags: http, authorization, http-status-codes

I am implementing a simple registation/login module.

While testing user credentials, I start thinking which HTTP status code will be appropriate, for the situation if a user send a request with incorrect credentials.

At first, I thought 401 Unauthorized would be a nice status code, but it seems it will be better to use it when a user is trying to get some resource without authorisation.

After, I switched to 409 Conflict

> This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.

So, friends, please give me an advise, which status code should be used.

Comment: using a resource without authorization should be a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs "The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to 401, but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource."

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you use HTTP authentication as defined by RFC 7235, [401](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) would be correct (for missing or incorrect credentials). Howewer you have to implement [WWW-Authenticate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) header field.

Otherwise, use [RFC 7231 6.5.3. 403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3).

Note though that 404 is also applicable as per the above link:

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a
> forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of
> 404 (Not Found).