# What status code should a REST API return for login requests performed with wrong credentials?

Tags: rest, authentication, httpresponse

I have found a lot of answers and explanations for the meanings of HTTP status codes. My question is specifically about the POST request to a login endpoint, which asks for username and password and an invalid combination is provided.

Some thoughts:

**400 Bad Response**
I think this code is not appropriate, because it says the request was syntactically incorrect and not understood by the server, which is not the case here. The login data is just semantically not correct.

**401 Unauthorized**
Here is the tricky part for me.
If 401 can only occur on requests requiring an authentication header then this is not correct. But if 401 can occur on all requests, which require authentication (either as header or in the body) then 401 is a candidate.

**403 Forbidden**
Usually, 403 is returned if the user already is authenticated and known to the system but requested a resource he/she is not allowed to access.
The user definitely is not authenticated before the login. I don't know if there is a semantic for 403 for unauthenticated users.

I'm happy to be told the answer or hear your thoughts.

Comment: Everything you have written seems to be correct and I do not see any questions

Comment: the question is in the title

Comment: Throw 'em a teapot error. Why give hackers any information?

Comment: short answer: 401, long answer is in your question

Comment: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the appropriate HTTP status code to return if a user tries logging in with an incorrect username / password, but correct format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752578/whats-the-appropriate-http-status-code-to-return-if-a-user-tries-logging-in-wit)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If a user is attempting to authenticate, but provides invalid credentials, the response should have a status of 401, regardless of if you are using Basic Authorization or not. 401 indicates that authentication failed, but the user can alter their request and attempt again.

If a user is authenticated, but not authorized to access the requested resource, then the response should have a status of 403. 403 indicates that the user is forbidden from accessing the resource, and no matter how they alter the request, they will not be permitted access.

In the scenario that your endpoint requires the credentials to be in the body of the request, you should return a 400 if the request body does not meet your specifications.

Comment: is there any documentation for this? I mean who says we can't send 200 status code in response and mention the reason in body? (I know it's not a good practice but I'm looking for a book or reference)

Comment: Here is the specification: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Ultimately, you can design your endpoints however you want, and document accordingly. However, following a well-known standard will surprise your clients the least, and may even allow them to reuse some of their existing code.

Comment: Yeah always I have an argue with some developers who say better we reply 200 status code but in body we can reply a defined model with result that says authentication has failed for this reason! thanks Joshua

Answer (score 3):

> My question is specifically about the `POST` request to a login endpoint, which asks for username and password for example and the scenario where incorrect ones are provided.

It depends on how the credentials are sent:

- If you are using [HTTP Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) (sending credentials in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header), you can return [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) to indicate that the credentials are invalid.
- If you send credentials in the request body (for example a JSON with username and password), [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) doesn't seem to be the most suitable status code (once it's not a *real* HTTP Authentication). In this situation, consider [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) instead with a descriptive response payload.

---

The [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) status code also can be used to indicate *authorization* problems, that is, to indicate that a user is not allowed to perform an action.

Comment: For the second bullet: 403 is Unauthorized and depends on the role or claims a user has which may be unsufficient for specific endpoints/resources and has nothing to do with credentials unknown to the api. In case of unknown combination username/password a 401 should be returned instead of 403.

And the misleading thing is that 401 is labeled as Unauthorized as it should state **Unauthenticated** and 403 Forbidden is actually Unauthorized.

Answer (score 2):

`401` for invalid credentials when using HTTP Authentication

`403` for user logged in but attempting to access area that is not allowed

Comment: _`401` for invalid credentials_ is not quite accurate. It should be: `401` for invalid credentials _when using [HTTP Authentication](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235)_

Comment: True!  Thanx, Cássio I've updated the answer to clarify.